# How to use object as a dictionary key in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I have the following simple class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

It's in Python but it shouldn't matter. I have a map/dictionary that uses instances of this class as keys. E.g.:

```
m = {
    A(a=1): 2,
    A(a=3, b=4): 5,
    A(b=6): 7
}
```

How can I configure this data in YAML? I've tried

```
{ a: 1 } : 2
{ a: 3, b: 4 } : 5
{ b: 6 } : 7
```

but I'm getting 'duplicated mapping key' error on the second line. I understand it's possible to write

```
[1, null] : 2
[3, 4] : 5
[null, 6] : 7
```

but I would like to keep named fields.

Alternatively, is there another configuration format that would let me do that?

Comment: It seems PyYAML doesn't support it yet: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/pull/654.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this issue by using explicit constructor

```
def yaml_a_constructor(loader, node):
    fields = loader.construct_mapping(node)
    return A(fields.get('a'), fields.get('b'))

yaml.add_constructor('!A', yaml_a_constructor)
```

and YAML

```
!A { a: 1 } : 2
!A { a: 3, b: 4 } : 5
!A { b: 6 } : 7
```

.